# $T(n) = 3T(n/2) + n$ -- why does this series not diverge?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

I'm trying to use a recursion tree to solve the recurrence $T(n) = 3T(n/2) + n$. After drawing out the tree, I can simplify the time formula to 
$$
T(n) = n(1 + \frac{3}{2} + \frac{3^2}{2^2} + \dots + \frac{3^{\log_2 n}}{2^{\log_2 n}})
$$
Now here's where I'm confused: why doesn't this series diverge? The common ratio, *r*, between the terms is $\frac{3}{2}$, which is greater than 1, so shouldn't this series diverge? I know by using Master's Theorem that the time complexity for this algorithm is $\Theta(n^{\log_2 3})$. How do we get to this conclusion from the time formula above?

Comment: I got $$T(n)=c_1 3^{\frac{\log (n)}{\log
   (2)}-1}-2 \left(n-3^{\frac{\log
   (n)}{\log (2)}}\right)$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner What is this solution for? Is that what you got as the final time complexity?

Comment: Yes it is the final rersult

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner But you can use Master's Theorem for this problem and the result should be $\Theta(n^{\log_2 3})$

Comment: Yeah, the two results are the same in asymptotics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does diverge. In fact
$$
1 + \frac{3}{2} + \frac{3^2}{2^2} + \dots + \frac{3^{\log_2 n}}{2^{\log_2 n}} = \frac{3^{\log_2 2n}}{n}-2
$$
which diverges.

How to get the desired form :
$$
\begin{aligned}
n\left (\frac{3^{\log_2 2n}}{n}-2\right  ) &= 3^{\log_2 2n} - 2n \\
&=  3^{\log_2 3 \log_3 2n}-2n\\
&= (2n)^{\log_2 3}-2n \\
&= \Theta(n ^{\log_2 3})
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: So then how would we solve for the geometric series resulting from the recursion tree if the series does diverge?

Comment: @apgriff1 I don't quite understand your question. Of course the result will diverge and the geometric series also should diverge. If the geometric series coverages, and the result will be $n \times c$($c$ is a constant which the series diverges to, and that means $\Theta(n)$) rather than $\Theta(n^{\log_2 3})$.

Comment: Sorry, to be more clear, I know from Master's Theorem that the time complexity for this algorithm is $\Theta(n^{log_2 3})$. How do we get from  $$
T(n) = n(1 + \frac{3}{2} + \frac{3^2}{2^2} + \dots + \frac{3^{\log_2 n}}{2^{\log_2 n}})
$$ to there if the series diverges?

Comment: @apgriff1, $n^a$ diverges for all $a\ge 1$

Comment: @apgriff1 I have updated.

Comment: @FFjet So I guess ultimately the question lies in how did you get to $\frac{3^{\log_2 {2n}}}{n} - 2$?

Comment: @apgriff1 That's the basics of geometric series. go [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) and you will find what you need.